# How can we override Dango ModelAdmin queryset over ModelForm queryset?

Tags: python, django, django-admin

Requirement is to display M2M instances in a dropdown for different logins. Each login will be able to see only instances belonging to their own domain. Since this dropdown is a dynamic list of table row values, I want to use

```
widget  = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple   which is part of the ModelForm where we need to pass the queryset. This queryset overrides the M2M form field definition:

 def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
```

It doesn't filter as per the login and displays all the objects.
I don't want to use the default <Ctrl +> for selection from the dropdown. Not very good with any JS related code. Please quide.  Sharing the snippets of code tried:

models.py:

```
class GroupA(models.Model):
    address = models.EmailField(
        unique=True,verbose_name='Email id of the group')
    mailboxes = models.ManyToManyField(Mailbox,
                                       related_name='my_mailboxes')

class GroupForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['mailboxes'].widget.attrs={"style":"height:100px;"}
        
    class Meta:
        model = GroupA
        fields = "__all__"
    mailboxes = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(
         queryset = Mailbox.objects.all(),
         widget  = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple
     )
```

In admin.py

```
class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = GroupForm
 
    def get_form(self, request, obj=None, **kwargs):
        kwargs['form'] = GroupForm
        Form = super().get_form(request, obj=None, **kwargs)
        return functools.partial(Form, 
mailboxes=Mailbox.objects.filter(
            domain__customer__email=request.user.email))
    '''
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "mailboxes":
            #if request.user.groups.filter(name__in=['customers']).exists():
            kwargs["queryset"] = Mailbox.objects.filter(
                domain__customer__email=request.user.email)
            #print(kwargs["queryset"], 'qqqqqq')
            for k in kwargs["queryset"]:
                print(k, 'kkkkkkkkkk')
        return super(GroupAdmin, self).formfield_for_manytomany(
            db_field, request, **kwargs)
    '''
```

Filtering works when we don't use the MultiCheckbox widget. Want to have filtered checkboxes. Using django3.2. python3.8. Please guide

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat can you plz elaborate in this context the code?

Comment: Using the above answer you can pass a keyword argument to your form's `__init__` method, so you could modify your field's queryset there

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Updated the above admin/models code.But filtering is still not happening for Checkbox widget

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the django model admin code, not sure why but it seems `ModelAdmin` does not respect the many-to-many field configured in the custom form.

But if you want filtered checkboxes, you can do something like this in `formfield_for_manytomany`:

```py
from django import forms

class GroupAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # ...
    def formfield_for_manytomany(self, db_field, request, **kwargs):
        if db_field.name == "mailboxes":
            kwargs["queryset"] = Mailbox.objects.filter(
                domain__customer__email=request.user.email
            )
            kwargs["widget"] = forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple

        return super().formfield_for_manytomany(db_field, request, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thans this worked after carefully removing some methods defined on the ModelForm